# Can Flow Update Field using a formula once and then allow users to edit the field later?

Tags: visual-workflow, formula-field, field-update

I want to use flow to update a field on account level using formula  once an Opportunity has been Closed Won ( so Closing Winning and Opportunity would trigger the flow), after the field has been updated, Im wondering, can Users be allowed to edit this field afterwards, and then once a new Opportunity is Closed Won again Flow would update this field using a formula (just once) and again users would be allowed to overwrite the value Flow inserted if its not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just make a Process Builder or Flow that updates the account when the Opportunity moves to Closed Won (e.g. you could trigger on `NOT(PRIORVALUE(IsWon)) && IsWon`) that updates the Account. This should be a pretty trivial customization.